# Is it ok to hang the bike by the frame, if the bowden is on the bottom?

Tags: brakes, frames, storage

Related: there are plenty of Q&A's (both here and on other sides), according to which, apparently, it is ok to hang a bike by its wheel.

What I didn't find though is, if it is ok to hang the bike by the frame, if the bowden goes below the frame, **thus the bowden cable and the frame would be pushed together**. Could it e.g. cause the bowden to wear quicker? Or slightly misadjust the rear brake?

Especially if the bike hangs for longer periods, say up to six months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do it often it could scratch the frame’s paint or damage the cable over time. I don’t think it will have any other ill effects. It’s basically the same as if you’d set the cable length or tension a few millimeters too short. You could unhook the cable at the brake (no need to open the clamping screw).

Why don’t you hang it from the saddle? [image]

Comment: Follow-up question: doesn't that damage the saddle? :D

Comment: @Attilio: no, it does not.

Comment: The covering of some saddles wraps under, so the weight of he bike would be on the covering. Over time the saddle covering could crack from this. If the weight is being taken on the seat rails, then maybe a few cosmetic scratches.  A foam tube over the bracket will help.

Comment: Apparently pulling on the saddle [risks damaging the dropper post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/74257/3039). (Personally can't confirm this, I always pull my enduro bike up on the balcony by the saddle and the RockShox Reverb seems to handle it just fine.)

Answer (score 6):

Not going to do anything, unless the bike weighs 300 lbs or something.

Worst case if you're hanging and removing repeatedly you could scuff the paint, from the housing rubbing against the frame. But of course, your mounts pose the same risks.

Comment: If the bracket is covered in a soft foam, the weight is spread so no damage to cable. Scratching occurs from putting the bike on and taking it off - lift vertically rather than slide. the bike off and on.

Comment: Just put some frame protector on between the cabling and the frame in those spots.